# Choosing a mic for recording video on DSLR camera

Tags: microphone, recommendations

I am going to record some video using my Canon 7D Mark II camera.

The video is a presentation and I need better sound quality than the built in mic on the camera.

I have a Rode NT1 mic which has very good sound quality. But the problem is that, I don't want the mic to be visible in the video, so it needs to be outside the frame. I believe this will degrade the sound quality, since it is not as close to me as it should be, and I need to boost the sound, which results in boosting the background noise too.

Now, my question is, shall I go with the NT1 mic or is better to buy a lav mic?

And if you think a lav mic is better, which one do you recommend?

EDIT:

What I am trying to shoot is an online course, with me in front of the camera with a white background. I am recording in my own room, so there is some noise from the outside.

It is important to hide the mic, since I want to avoid anything which might distract the students.

Comment: It is hard to recommend anything when we don't know WHAT you are trying to shoot? Why do you not want the microphone in the frame?  Is invisible microphone more important than getting decent audio?  Why?

And we don't know what environment you are trying to record in.  Is it a nice quiet and "dead" studio where you don't need to worry about ambient noise or environmental reverberation, echo, etc.

Comment: @RichardCrowley I added some more details.

Answer (score 1):

A microphone like a common clip-on "lavaliere" microphone is used by 10s of thousands of news people every day on television and nobody thinks of them as "distracting". My first preference would be for a nearly-invisible "headset" microphone with a very small, nearly transparent "wand" which ends near your mouth.  That gives you the best pickup of your voice if you turn your head or move around, etc.  It also gives you the best "signal-to-noise ratio" because it puts the microphone much closer to your mouth than to any ambient noise or interference.

Comment: Can you suggest a couple headsets of that kind?

Comment: Large retailers like B&H have scores/hundreds to choose from.  Here are some low-price examples:
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Connector+Type_3.5mm+Mini+Plug&ci=3779&Ns=p_PRICE_2|0&N=4263084562+4263084994+4294950679